# Mix GFortran/MSVC objects when linking: undefined reference to _chkstk

Tags: visual-c++, linker, gfortran

Trying to compile Xfoil and plotlib

The fortran files are compiled with MinGW gfortran 4.5.0, and I compiled W32win.c with MSVC (2008/15.00).

During linking with GCC  I receive error:

```
../plotlib/libPlt.a(W32win.o):(.text+0x1469): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
../plotlib/libPlt.a(W32win.o):(.text+0x1509): undefined reference to `_chkstk'
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve?

The reason I am trying to use MSVC, is that when I compiled plotlib with gcc only, the plot window does not operate properly, and displays only a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command-line MSVC compiler, `cl.exe`, use the option `/Gs` to prevent it from emitting the calls to `_chkstk`.

Otherwise that is probably a check-box in the project options part of the MSVC GUI.

Either way, recompile W32win.c with the needed compiler setting and you should be one step farther along your path.